# Maintaining count between a range

Tags: ruby

Let me explain my problem, so I clear some confusion. I have an array of images, and I want to create a collage with them. So, I need to keep getting images from the array until the collage if done. If the collage is not done and the Array doesn't have more images, I need to get the images from the beginning of the array.

I want a count to be in the range of 0..(size_of_array - 1).

So I have this

```
size_of_array = my_array.size
count = 0

while (!collage_finished)
  item = my_array[count]
  collage_finished = insert_image_in_collage(item)
  count += 1
end
```

How can I make it so the count keeps looping from 0..(size_of_array-1) - I want to iterate more than once through my array. That's why I avoid doing `.each`.

Comment: Why iterate more than once? Why not just do what you need the first time around?

Comment: Because I want to use repeteadly the items of the array (images) to create a collage of images.

Comment: What's the point of assigning `my_array[count]` to a local variable? Why not pass it directly to the `insert_image_in_collage()` function?

Comment: I put that there for the sake of clarity on my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
while true
  my_array.each do |item|
    #do stuff with item
  end
end
```

Comment: I want to iterate several times through my array.

Comment: Creating infinite loops is considered poor practice.

Comment: @JustinWood: This loop is not necessarily infinite — it just doesn't have its termination prespecified.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just keep looping over a collection over and over, you can use `cycle`. So you'd do something like:

```
my_array.cycle do |item|
  # do something with the item
end
```

If you only want to cycle a certain number of times (which is often the case), you can pass a number argument to cycle specifying how many times you want to do it.

Comment: Actually, I want to cycle until a particular condition is found. I have edited my question to clarify why I want to iterate several times over the array.

Comment: @HommerSmith: You can do that too. Just break or return when the end condition occurs. I was just pointing out the argument for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 1):

What about doing this:

```
while (!collage_finished)
  item = my_array[count % size_of_array]
  collage_finished = insert_image_in_collage(item)
  count++
end
```

By doing `count % mod`, you will always be in the range of `0..(size_of_array - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

That is considered a poor way of doing things. You should do something like the following

```
my_array.each do |item|
  # do stuff with item
end
```

This will iterate over all items in your array and do whatever you need with it.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably use `each`, but you could also use something like this:

```
array.size.times do |iteration|
  item = array[iteration]
  ...
end
```